# .lnk shortcuts in Windows Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to create a windows form app that will be able to handle icons from desktop, like keeping them and changing their properties etc...Can you please give me some advice how to create this pseudo-desktop? I haven't found anything that allows me to place .lnk shortcuts on Form.

Thanks

Comment: Could you expand on that a bit. How exactly would you like to "handle" icons from the desktop? Drag drop?

Comment: I would like to crate an app that will serve as my desktop...in order for beter organization...It should be same as desktop but in more forms that will hold a category of shortcuts...like graphics processors(i keep a lot of them) or programing stuff etc...Simply...I'm trying to create multidesktop in Windows forms

Comment: This question is way too broad, in future try to distil your questions into something that is answerable. Simulating a desktop is a huge project, which would involve grabbing thumbnails, remembering positions and so on. If you are looking for an explanation of how to consume LNK files in c# it is easily answerable and a good fit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that, you do not need real LNK files (For creating them you need to use p/invoke).
Just make a ListView with Icon-View. If the User doubleclicke on a item you can handle the click and launch whatever you want to associate with this action.

Comment: And what if I don't want to keep icons on my desktop? Will ListView allow me to insert my own defined object(shortcut) into his items? I would like to crate a desktop that won't need to keep the old .lnk files to point at them when I want to call them. I think ListView can kepp only ListViewItems, or not?